# Pandas add minutes from other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'time':['10:45:00', '09:30:00', '17:00:00', '15:50:00'], 'minutes_to_be_add': [10, 5, 7, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to create a new column `future_time` by adding the minutes from `minutes_to_be_added` column to the `time` column. `time` column has a datatype `datetime64[ns]` and `minutes_to_be_added` column has a datatype `object`. I have tried using `timedelta` but couldn't work.

Expected output:

```
future_time
10:55:00
09:35:00
17:07:00
16:10:00
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` to have the exact type?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timedeltas:

```
(pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
   .add(pd.to_timedelta(df['minutes_to_be_add'], unit='m'))
   .astype(str).str[-9:]
)
```

output:

```
0     10:55:00
1     09:35:00
2     17:07:00
3     16:10:00
dtype: object
```